# How to implement Quill Emoji Blot

Tags: javascript, quill

I am trying to implement an Emoji Blot to Quill Editor,

But I have some issues with the cursor on editor.

In order to solve this I added a space after the emoji insertion, but when I try to remove them is needed two backspaces to remove the emoji. On the first time the cursor stops at the beginning of the emoji, and on the second time the emoji is removed.

Does anyone already did something similar to this? How can I get this code to work properly?

Thanks in any advance.

```js
const Embed = Quill.import("blots/embed");
class EmojiBlot extends Embed {
  static create(classes) {
    let node = super.create();
    classes.split(" ").forEach(iconClass => {
      node.classList.add(iconClass);
    });
    return node;
  }

  static formats(node) {
    let format = {};
    if (node.hasAttribute("class")) {
      format.class = node.getAttribute("class");
    }
    return format;
  }

  static value(node) {
    return node.getAttribute("class");
  }

  format(name, value) {
    if (name === "class") {
      if (value) {
        this.domNode.setAttribute(name, value);
      } else {
        this.domNode.removeAttribute(name, value);
      }
    } else {
      super.format(name, value);
    }
  }
}

EmojiBlot.blotName = "emoji";
EmojiBlot.tagName = "span";
Quill.register({
  "formats/emoji": EmojiBlot
});

var myEditor = new Quill("#editor-container", {
  modules: {
    toolbar: document.getElementById("toolbar")
  },
  placeholder: "Compose an epic...",
  theme: "snow" // or 'bubble'
});

const insertEmoji = function() {
  let editorSelection = myEditor.getSelection();
  const cursorPosition = editorSelection && editorSelection.index ? editorSelection.index : 0;
  myEditor.insertEmbed(cursorPosition, "emoji", 'icon icon-smiley');
  myEditor.insertText(cursorPosition + 1, ' ')
  myEditor.setSelection(cursorPosition + 2)
};
document.querySelector(".emojiButton").addEventListener("click", insertEmoji);
```

```css
#editor-container {
  height: 200px;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin: 0 .05em 0 .1em;
  vertical-align: -0.1em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 1em 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-smiley {
  background-image: url("https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/2/svg/1f603.svg"); 
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.5/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.5/quill.js"></script>
<div
    id="editor-container"
></div>
<div id="toolbar">
    <button class="ql-bold"></button>
    <button class="ql-italic"></button>
    <button class="emojiButton">:D</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm actually running into the same issue with a similar implementation. In addition quill seems to be capturing spaces after my inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the emoji tag from a span to an img and also replaced:

```
myEditor.insertText(cursorPosition + 1, ' ')
myEditor.setSelection(cursorPosition + 2)
```

With

```
myEditor.setSelection(cursorPosition + 1);
```

This solves the issue. See an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/nadavrt/Ldgfp5pa/

As to what is causing the span the misbehave, my guess is that Quill fails to register your Blot's width correctly due to an error in Quill itself. I would recommend that you open a bug issue on the project's GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answear, it will be of great help.  

I just add one more line on the create method of `IconBlot`  

`node.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7')`  

To add a src attribute to the element, this way the browser will not display the border on the image.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. If you are interested in implementing multiple Emoji you might also want to take a look at this GitHub page: https://github.com/contentco/quill-emoji

Comment: @Nadav Upvoted for the jsfiddle, helped me with the issue I was facing. Thx !